# What does the phrase "I didn't bring my permits" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, humor

I came across this gif. Apparently actor Chris Pratt is cracking some kind of a joke here, but I'm not sure if I get it. He said this line after he had showed off his guns.

[image: so here it is]

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

He's talking about a [CCW permit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concealed_carry_in_the_United_States). It is a legal document, similar to a driver's licence, for example, which you have to carry with you every time you carry a (concealed) gun.

If he brought his guns, but not his permit, he probably shows off how courageous (or stupid) he is.

I don't know more about the context, however, only what you've provided, so there's that.

EDIT: Another thing I thought of is that he does not refer to literal guns, but to his body part(s). Saying he needs a permit for those implies the body part(s) are huge.

Comment: your second guess is absolutely right. I should've used the word biceps instead of guns! my apology. I think that's exactly what he meant!

Answer (score 0):

Since well-muscled arms are sometimes called 'guns', and (in the United States) a permit is required to carry a gun, it is a joke of juxtaposition. Effectively, this is the same as saying "I should need a permit to carry these."

Comment: And My thanks go as well to you, sir! Now I got his joke perfectly.